# How to display the label of an Antd Form.Item to the right of the input field?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design React and I want to create a form where the label of a Form.Item is displayed to the right of the input field.

By default, the label is displayed to the left of the input field. I tried to set the labelAlign property to "right", but that only changes the text alignment of the label. How can I change the position of the label?

```
<Form.Item
  name={"isPickup"}
  label={t("booking.field.isPickup")}
  colon={false}
  valuePropName="checked"
>
  <Switch />
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the label to the right of the input field, you can use the labelCol and wrapperCol properties to adjust the columns. This also includes the `style` attribute, where you can set the CSS property `order: 2` to the `labelCol` to change the order in the flex row that the `Form.Item` creates.

For example:

```
<Form.Item
  name={"isPickup"}
  label={t("booking.field.isPickup")}
  colon={false}
  valuePropName="checked"
  labelCol={{ style: { order: 2 } }}
>
  <Switch />
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the label of an Antd Form.Item to the right of the input field, you can make use of the Antd Grid system.

```
<Form.Item
  name={"isPickup"}
  label={t("booking.field.isPickup")}
  colon={false}
  wrapperCol={{ sm: { offset: 8 } }} // Adjust the offset value according to your requirements
  valuePropName="checked"
>
  <Row>
    <Col flex="auto">
      <Switch />
    </Col>
    <Col style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
      {t("booking.field.isPickup")} {/* Display the label to the right */}
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: If you have any element within Form.Item, you loose the 2 way data binding, so this for doesn't map its data anymore.